# Implementing a CorDapp emulating a bank

Tags: corda

I have just started learning the workings of R3 Corda and want to create a small CorDapp of Bank in which there will be one bank that will issue cash for users who can then spend or transfer to other nodes.
I want to use cash state as well as the cash contract.So, I am not able to understand how can I use them .
Do I make my own state or contract or directly create flows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tokens SDK** has all that functionality, you don't have to implement anything yourself. Just use the provided data types and flows; below is a link to the most common tasks that you can achieve with the SDK:
https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/master/docs/IWantTo.md

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Corda finance module. It sort of implements the use case you are interested in: https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/release/os/4.5/finance.

Have a look at the [CashIssueFlow](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.5/finance/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/flows/CashIssueFlow.kt) which is used to issue the [Cash](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.5/finance/contracts/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/Cash.kt) and the [CashPaymentFlow](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.5/finance/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/flows/CashPaymentFlow.kt) that is used to transfer the cash to another party.

Though the finance module would be replaced by the TokenSDK in the future, it is a good reference to try and understand how to implement such use case in Corda.